# Is missed step detection of a stepper motor done is software or hardware?

Tags: stepper-motor, embedded-systems, stepper-driver

I remember seeing a video of the Prusa i3 Mk3 printer. It can detect when
the stepper motor misses a step, so it can home itself again.

I would like to know how this is done!

There are a few options I can imagine:

1. This can be done using standard stepper motors and stepper motor drivers, the detection is done entirely in software.
2. This can be done using standard stepper motors, but requires some extra circuitry as well as software.
3. This can only be done with special stepper motors and other components and special software.

Which option is correct? Any of the above, or something completely different? If you have any references, such a links, articles or blog posts on how to do missed step detection, it would be very interesting also!

Comment: This video shows missed step detection. https://prusaclone.wordpress.com/2018/03/01/missed-step-detection-with-mk2clone-r2/ ........... most likely detects the current spike

Comment: Please remember to *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* @jsotola

Comment: i am not trying to be nasty ... i did a quick web search for *missed step detection youtube* ..... that video came up at the top of the search results .... that is why i asked if any research has been done .... if the OP referred to something like that video and asked how the detection is done, then it would be a totally different situation

Comment: Your comment was the verbal equivalent of let me google that for you links, which are banned on stack exchange as they are not considered nice. I didn't want to delete your comment as the link is useful, but please understand how your comment might be perceived by others, even if you didn't intend it to be insulting @jsotola

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the link to the video! This is probably the one remembering seeing, I should have included a link. It doesn't leave me any wiser when it comes to _how_ it is actually done, though. Can I ask you to please elaborate on what you mean by "most likely detects the current spike", and how would this be done in practice?

Comment: This answers the questions very well: https://github.com/laurb9/StepperDriver/issues/55